# Racing condition in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, async-await

I have a race condition with the items query below. The select miIds.ItemId doesn't wait for the allItemList database call to finish returning all of it's results. What would be the best way to address the problem? Should I pull the query out of the task and wait for it to return before kicking off the query, or is there something I can do within my query to make it wait?
Thank you.

```
    private async Task LoadData()
    {
        // Query Mission_Item Ids.
        var missionItemsList = await App.Database.GetTableAsync<Mission_Items_Model>();
        var missionItemIds = from missionItem in missionItemsList
                             where missionItem.MissionId == game.CurrentMissionId
                             select missionItem;

        // Query All Items, select item where item's itemIds match mission's itemIds.
        var allItemList = await App.Database.GetTableAsync<ItemModel>();
        var items = from item in allItemList
                    let mi = (from miIds in missionItemIds where miIds.ItemId == item.Id select miIds.ItemId)
                    where mi.Contains(item.Id)
                    select item;

        // Item list for mission.
        ItemsList = new List<ItemModel>(items);

        ...

    }
```

Comment: how can you use `await` and have a race condition ? Are you sure you do understand the problem ?

Comment: Thank you! When I run the code missionItemsList returns a random number of objects each time. If I comment out the linq query, then missionItemsList always returns the correct item count. I though that the select miIds.ItemId was forcing the database call to run synchronously. Which doesn't really make sense, I see now, that wanted I really wanted to select was the item.Id instead of the miIds.ItemId.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simple, it is resulting from the usage of `var` that hides that the query `missionItemIds` is not being enumerated. To cause that query to actually execute, you need to use a call that materialize the sequence (`.ToList()` for example):

```
var missionItemIds = (from missionItem in missionItemsList
                     where missionItem.MissionId == game.CurrentMissionId
                     select missionItem).ToList();
```

It seems that `game.CurrentMissionId` is changing by the time your actually materialize the results.